# Postregsql transform one retrieved record into two records based on columns value

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I have two Postgresql tables:

```
Searches:
+----+------------+-----------+-----------+
| id | patient_id | status_a  | status_b  |
+----+------------+-----------+-----------+
| 1  | 1          | Added     | Added     |
+----+------------+-----------+-----------+
| 2  | 2          | Added     | NULL      |
+----+------------+-----------+-----------+

Patients:
+----+------+---------+
| id | name | country |
+----+------+---------+
| 1  | John | England |
+----+------+---------+
| 2  | Tim  | France  |
+----+------+---------+
```

I would like to retrieve "all the patients that have the `status_a` OR the `status_b` set to 'Added', creating a different record depending on the value of the status columns".

I need to be able to achieve this:

```
+------------+------+---------+-----------+-----------+
| patient_id | name | country | status_a  | status_b  |
+------------+------+---------+-----------+-----------+
| 1          | John | England | Added     | NULL      |
+------------+------+---------+-----------+-----------+
| 1          | John | England | Null      | Added     |
+------------+------+---------+-----------+-----------+
| 2          | Tim  | France  | Added     | NULL      |
+------------+------+---------+-----------+-----------+
```

Or, even better:

```
+------------+------+---------+-----------+
| patient_id | name | country | status    |
+------------+------+---------+-----------+
| 1          | John | England | A         |
+------------+------+---------+-----------+
| 1          | John | England | B         |
+------------+------+---------+-----------+
| 2          | Tim  | France  | A         |
+------------+------+---------+-----------+
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 2):

You need to pivot the `searches` table into rows using `union`.

```
select p.id as patient_id, p.name, p.country, s.status
  from patients p
       join (select patient_id, 'A' as status
               from searches
              where status_a is not null
             union
             select patient_id, 'B' as status
               from searches
              where status_b is not null) as s
         on s.patient_id = p.id
 order by p.id, s.status;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a lateral join:

```
select s.patient_id, p.name, p.country, v.status_a, v.status_b
from searches s cross join lateral
     (values (status_a, null),
             (null, status_b)
     ) v(status_a, status_b) join
     patients p
     on p.id = s.patient_id
where v.status_a is not null or v.status_b is not null;
```